# iOS Optical Character Recognition - Characters in a Grid

Tags: ios, swift, tesseract

What is the best way to go about reading characters in a grid-like format, like a Sudoku puzzle? I tried using [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/93276/implementing-tesseract-ocr-ios) tutorial to get started with Tesseract OCR, but it was pretty inconsistent even with similar fonts. I want to be able to read a pattern of characters and store it in a multidimensional array. How can I train Tesseract to do this like I would train it to interpret different fonts?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with OpenCV (http://opencv.org/) to interpret the Sudoku grid  and then I would recognise the numbers using Tesseract. You can check these tutorials: https://www.raywenderlich.com/93276/implementing-tesseract-ocr-ios, https://github.com/BloodAxe/OpenCV-Tutorial and https://github.com/aptogo/OpenCVForiPhone. I hope it helps you.